# File I/O Redirect System.in fails while Normal file read with given path works properly

Tags: java, arrays, pcap, io-redirection, system.in

I am reading a PCAP file byte by byte in Java using IO-Redirection System.in.
It does not reads the bytes in correct manner.
I am using

```
System.in.read(byte[], int off, int len);
```

When I do the same thing with

```
InputStream is = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(new File(filepath))));
is.read(byte[], int off, int len);
```

It works properly.

Any idead why?